# Browser does not apply style before heavy workload

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom

I would like to redraw a portion of my page that holds a lot of DOM elements. Ideally, I would like to set `visibility: hidden;`, redraw the portion, then set `visibility: visible;`. However, Chrome seems to ignore my javascript for setting the CSS.

If you uncomment the `debugger` lines, you'll see that Chrome actually renders things correctly while debugging. This may not be Chrome specific.

In case the SO code snippet doesn't work, I also made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/cq4fd3vo/).

```js
//debugger;

var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.style.visibility = "hidden";

//debugger;

// In my case, some d3 code that draws SVG elements
// In this case, something that makes the browser work for x seconds
var delay = 3000,
  counter = 1000;

var t0 = new Date().getTime(),
  t1 = undefined;

while ((t1 = new Date().getTime()) <= t0 + delay) {
  if (t1 >= t0 + counter) {
    console.log(counter);
    counter += 1000;
  }
}

container.style.visibility = "visible";
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
  <div>Some DOM Element</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can we figure out how your DOM manipulation is lagging Chrome, without _any_ of the DOM manipulation code? There's nothing left to work with. Please post your actual DOM code so we can tell what's going on.

Comment: Maybe my title is misleading, but my code shows that Chrome hangs. So it's not the DOM manipulation code.

Comment: Then the title _is_ misleading - I can't figure out what you intend to ask exactly, but I'd recommend updating it to something that's clearer. As it stands, I don't understand the question at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome doesn't instantaneously apply your DOM changes, until the javascript thread frees up or something causes it to have to render.

You can move your code into a callback function that will run after ... well, 0ms, or whenever the JS engine can next run it.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.style.visibility = "hidden";

setTimeout(function () {

    // In my case, some d3 code that draws SVG elements
    // In this case, something that makes the browser work for x seconds
    var delay = 3000, counter = 1000;

    var t0 = new Date().getTime(), t1 = undefined;

    while ((t1 = new Date().getTime()) <= t0 + delay) {
        if (t1 >= t0 + counter) {
            console.log(counter);
            counter += 1000;
        }
    }

    container.style.visibility = "visible";
}, 0);
```

So your code will change your visibility CSS, register a callback to run next, then return.
Then the browser has a dom change to render, so it does that and repaints. Then runs your callback.

Basically, think of it as 1 big single-threaded process.

Comment: Thanks, worked great! FYI, I had to change the delay to at least 10ms or 100ms for it to work.